# how to transfer an numpy array into another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that returns a numpy array every second , that i want to store in another array for reference. for eg (array_a is returned)

```
array_a = [[    25.       50.       25.       25.       50.  ]
           [     1.        1.        1.        1.        1.  ]]

array_collect = np.append(array_a,array_collect)
```

But when i Print array_collect , i get an added array, not a bigger array with arrays inside it.

```
 array_collect = [    25.       50.       25.       25.       50.  
                       1.        1.        1.        1.        1.  
                       25.       50.       25.       25.       50.  
                       1.        1.        1.        1.        1.  
                       25.       50.       25.       25.       50.  ]
```

what i want is

```
 array_collect = [   [[  25.     50.       25.       25.       50.  ]
                      [1.        1.        1.        1.        1.   ]] 
                     [[  25.     50.       25.       25.       50.  ]
                      [1.        1.        1.        1.        1.   ]]
                     [[  25.     50.       25.       25.       50.  ]
                      [1.        1.        1.        1.        1.   ]]  ]
```

How do i get it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vstack`:

```
array_collect = np.array([[25.,50.,25.,25.,50.],[1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]])
array_a = np.array([[2.,5.,2.,2.,5.],[1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]])


array_collect=np.vstack((array_collect,array_a))
```

However, if you know the total number of minutes in advance, it would be better to define your array first (e.g. using `zeros`) and gradually fill it - this way, it is easier to stay within memory limits.

```
no_minutes = 5 #say 5 minutes
array_collect = np.zeros((no_minutes,array_a.shape[0],array_a.shape[1]))
```

Then, for every minute, m

```
array_collect[m] = array_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `np.concatenate()` and `reshape` this way:

```py
import numpy as np


array_collect = np.array([[25.,50.,25.,25.,50.],[1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]])
array_a = np.array([[2.,5.,2.,2.,5.],[1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]])

array_collect = np.concatenate((array_collect,array_a),axis=0).reshape(2,2,5)

>>

[[[ 25.  50.  25.  25.  50.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]

 [[  2.   5.   2.   2.   5.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it , this can be done by using :

```
 np.reshape()
```

the new array formed can be reshaped using

```
y= np.reshape(y,(a,b,c))
```

where a is the no. of arrays stores and (b,c) is the shape of the original array